# error when returning an XElement type as an object in a WCF service

Tags: wcf, serialization, xelement

Here is my operation contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    object Move();

}
```

Here is the implementation for the operation contract. I want to return XElement as an object, leaving client to convert the object back to XElement

```
public object Move()
    {
        object _x;

            var xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
                                        new XElement("Child", 1),
                                        new XElement("Child", 2),
                                        new XElement("Child", 3),
                                        new XElement("Child", 4),
                                        new XElement("Child", 5),
                                        new XElement("Child", 6)
                );

            var xmlTree2 = new XElement("Root",
                                        from el in xmlTree1.Elements()
                                        where ((int) el >= 3 && (int) el <= 5)
                                        select el


                );

            _x = xmlTree2;

            return _x;

    }
```

Here is the client code:

```
XElement _xmlelem;

ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient();

_xmlelem = (XElement)sc.Move();
```

Below is the stack strace of the error message:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.IService.Move()
   at ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient.Move() in C:\Delete\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 128
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Delete\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 20
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a WCF service to deserialize a .NET type (XElement in your case) to a requesting client and then have the client cast the .NET object type return value to a XElement type. WCF doesn't support that kind of deserialization unless you configure it for .NET serialization by [using the NetDataContractSerializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/15/datacontractserializer-vs-netdatacontractserializer.aspx) instead of the standard DataContractSerializer.

There are a lot of constraints to using [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx) so generally it is not a good practice. I believe you'd be better off returning straight XML. The answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652146/service-parameter-always-null-but-i-can-see-it-in-the-trace/6653176#6653176) shows how to deal with XML in a data contract.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to configure NetDataContractSeriliazer in config files?

Comment: After adding  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(XElement))] to the OperationContract, i am getting the below error - does this ring  any bells?
 Add the type corresponding to 'XElement' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer

Comment: The only sample I've run across is in the [WCF 4 samples from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459) in the solution at WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Basic\Contract\Data\NetDCSasDCSwithDCR\CS folder. You also need to implement an [OperationBehavior for swapping out](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/214152/507252.aspx) the standard serializer. All this required work should you give pause since all you just want to do is move some XML over the wire :)

Comment: One thing you **cannot** do is to use the XElement type in your service contract. Remember the constraints I mentioned? A big one is you can only serialize classes that implement ISerializable. XElement does not implement that interface so it can't be used.

Comment: ok. so you mean to say, in other words, the return type of an operation contract should implement ISerializable (in order to serialize). In case of XElement it is implementing IXmlSerializable and hence can not use. Please confirm.

Comment: Right, XElement isn't supported by the NetDataContractSerializer [as stated in this document at the Incompatibility with XElement section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx)

Comment: Instead of having object as return type to my operation contract, if I keep XElement as return type, then it is working as expected. I think this is due to the fact that XElement is implementing IXmlSerializable . But here in my case i was struck with object return type

Comment: so what i did was instead of returning Xelement as object, i have created an XMLDocument from XElement and returned XMLdocument's InnerXML as string. I could able to re-create XElement from this string on client side. Just want to know whether this is correct? are there any limitations with this approach?